# Load data from database to memory pool [gwan]

Tags: mysql, caching, g-wan

I currently writing a C program to cache data from Mysql to gwan cache (for a faster response from server to client), but I dont know how to let the program automatically initiate when the gwan start...

What could I do? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cache data from Mysql to gwan cache

The G-WAN cache is rather aimed at storing ready-to-serve pre-built HTTP replies.

If you want to cache raw mySQL responses (then picked by servlets to built HTTP replies) then you should consider using the G-WAN KV store.

See the [kv.c](http://gwan.ch/source/kv.c) source code example.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code into init() function inside your handler.

Comment: could you please in detail ?

Comment: Moryia, look at the handler examples under gwan/.../handlers

Comment: You can also use persistence from servlets (that's easier), have a look at the persistence.c example.